# Removable glue for Surface Pro 2 Monitor

Tags: lcd, display

I have recently replaced the monitor on my surface Pro 2 and I have duct taped it onto the tablet, however it keeps registering ghost touches which disables the mouse pad. I was wondering is there a easy to remove glue I can use to glue it in but have access to change anything I want later?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider Polyamid tape.  aka Kapton tape.  Stiff ( prevents stretching, but flexible) & thin used in electronic assy and flex circuit board laminate.

Or ...consider foil with thin doubled sided tape used in furnace duct joints.  (may improve capacitive coupling to frame)

Or consider  clear SIlicone sealant around edges, Easier to remove with plastic scraper, but less rigid if thick.

Comment: Another potential solution: I think it's 3M that makes a mounting tape that's cleanly removable by stretching it.  Not sure how/what you're taping, so how you would need to adapt this for your use.